# Child can't have min-height if parent does also? Trying to make a sticky footer

Tags: html, footer, css

As the subject says, I can't seem to get min-height to work on an element when it's parent also has min-height set. I've written up a jsfiddle example to show you what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/cE29B/5/

My purpose of this is of course to have a footer that's always at the bottom of the window, or site, depending on site size.

Would anyone happen to know how to get around this problem and still have that footer where I want it?

Thank you!!

EDIT: To be more clear, the main problem here is that #content (green background) is only one line high when the CSS says it should have a minimum height of 100%. This works if it's parent has a height that's either % or px, or a min-height that's only px. A % min-height breaks the child's % min-height.

Comment: What about css `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: I checked the fiddle and it seemed to work fine... What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Position: fixed would, well, fix it's position to the bottom of the browser, but I want the footer to always be below the content even with a scroll bar. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Oofpez, sorry I probably could have been a tad clearer. If you look at my jsfiddle, you'll notice that the content, with the green background, has a height of only one line, when the min-height should be 100% of the height of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can give your footer position and bottom 0;

remove margin-top as like this check to live http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/cE29B/8/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but do you notice how the content isn't 100% height as the CSS says it should be? That's my main problem here, even if the footer does exactly what we want, the content can't have min-height of 100% if it's parent does also. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: Using this solution, apply padding to the bottom of the main container of an equal height to the footer (which is absolutely positioned). Bet that will get you to where you want to be.